# Minimum of $f(z) = \left|z^2+z+1\right|+\left|z^2-z+1\right|$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, calculate the minimum value of
>
> $$
> f(z) = \left|z^2+z+1\right|+\left|z^2-z+1\right|
> $$

**My Attempt:**

Let $z= x+iy$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
z^2+z+1 &= (x+iy)^2+(x+iy)+1\\
&= (x^2-y^2+x+1)+i(2xy+y)
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
z^2-z+1 &= (x+iy)^2-(x+iy)+1\\
&= (x^2-y^2-x+1)+i(2xy-y)
\end{align}
$$

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by

$$
f(x,y) = \sqrt{\big(x^2-y^2+x+1\big)^2+(2xy+y)^2}+\sqrt{\big(x^2-y^2-x+1\big)^2+(y-2xy)^2}
$$

Using the Triangle Inequality, we know that

$$
f(x,y) \geq 2\sqrt{\left(x^2-y^2+1\right)^2+y^2}
$$

How can the problem be solved from this point?

Comment: if you put $x = 0,$ then $f \ge 2\sqrt{y^4 - y^2 + 1} \ge 2\sqrt{3/4} = \sqrt 3$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can write $f$ in the form
$$f(z)=2|z|\>\left(\left|J(z)-{1\over2}\right|+\left|J(z)+{1\over2}\right|\right)\ ,$$
where $J$ denotes the so-called *Joukowski function*:
$$J(z):={1\over2}\left(z+{1\over z}\right)\ .$$
It is well known that $J$ maps circles $|z|=r$ onto ellipses centered at $0$ with foci $\pm1$ and semiaxes $$a={1\over2}\left(r+{1\over r}\right),\quad b={1\over2}\left|r-{1\over r}\right|\ .$$ Looking at such an ellipse we see that the points minimizing $f$ are the points $J(\pm i r)$ on the imaginary axis. It follows that
$$g(r):=\min_{|z|=r} f(z)=f(ir)=2\sqrt{(r^2-1)^2+r^2}\ .$$
Now we have to minimize the right side over $r\geq0$. This leads to the equation
$4r^3-2r=0$ with the solutions $r_1=0$, $r_2={1\over\sqrt{2}}$. Since $g(0)=2$ and $g\bigl({1\over\sqrt{2}}\bigr)=\sqrt{3}$ we conclude that the global minimum of $f$ on the complex plane is $\sqrt{3}$, and this minimum is taken at the points $\pm{i\over\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis starts the right way. Substituting $z=x+iy$, you get as you write:

$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2+x+1)^2+(2xy+y)^2}+\sqrt{(x^2-y^2-x+1)^2+(y-2xy)^2}$$

The above now is a real multivariable function, so standard calculus techniques apply. In particular, the critical points are determined by looking first at the system:

$$\frac{df}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac{df}{dy}=0$$

This system has the solutions:

$$(x,y)=(0,0)$$

and

$$(x,y)=\left(0,\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$

The null solution is rejected because it is not a global extremum and you are left with the second solution which after switching back to complex variables corresponds to:

$$\left(x=0,y=\pm\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

as Cristian points out.

Here's the corresponding graph in two variables:

[image]

Comment: How did you solve the system?

Comment: @Alex Ravsky: Using a standard trick for such cases. In this case, minimizing $f(x,y)$ is (almost) equivalent to minimizing the same expression sans the radicals. This will introduce only some spurious solutions which you can drop later. If you drop the radicals, the system reduces to: $8x^3+8y^2x+12x=0$ and $8x^2y+8y^3-4y=0$, which is doable. To be sure, I also verified it with Maple.

Answer (score 1):

Using $A.M\geq G.M$ inequality we have $$\frac{|z^2-z+1|+|z^2+z+1|}{2}\geq \sqrt{|z^2-z+1||z^2+z+1|}$$The equality occurs if

$|z^2-z+1|=|z^2+z+1|$$\Rightarrow|z^2-z+1|^2=|z^2+z+1|^2$

$\Rightarrow |z^2+1|^2+|z|^2+(\bar z^2+1)z+(z^2+1)\bar z=|z^2+1|^2+|z|^2-(\bar z^2+1)z-(z^2+1)\bar z$

$\Rightarrow(|z|^2+1)(z+\bar z)=0$

$\Rightarrow Re(z)=0$

So if $z=x+iy$ then $x=0$ $\Rightarrow z=iy$

$$f_{min}(z)=f_{min}(iy)=|-y^2-iy+1|+|-y^2+iy+1|=2\sqrt{(1-y^2)^2+y^2}=2\sqrt{\left(y^2-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}$$

$f(z)\geq \sqrt{3}$

Also, I tried another line of thinking where we may write $f(z)$ as

$f(z)=|z+\omega||z+\omega^2|+|z-\omega||z-\omega^2|$ where $\omega$ is the complex cube root of unity. I tried to use triangle inequality and Ptolemy's theorem but could not come up with any plausible solution.